# How to export Oozie coordinators in Hue v3.7?

Tags: hadoop, oozie, hue, oozie-coordinator

I'd like to know how one can export coordinators in Hue 3.7, as I think it's not yet possible through the UI in that version. Is there a place on the Hue node where these are stored, or some manual exercise to the configs out? I need to have some export for backup/migration purposes.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

**3.7**
It is possible only by moving the Hue table data at the database level: http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera/en/documentation/core/latest/topics/cdh_ig_hue_database.html

**3.8**
Makes it a bit simpler on the CLI with a Hue command: http://gethue.com/export-and-import-your-oozie-workflows/

**3.9**
Will let you do it directly from the UI:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/kkonzrnco1lools/export-workflows.ogv?dl=0